# wp query problem

Tags: wp-query, themes

I am using wp-postviews   plugin to  to track views of my post
The author provided a query to order post by views in index.php

```
 <?php query_posts('v_sortby=views&amp;v_orderby=desc') ?>
```

But when I am using the same key with diff query it isn't working 
This is my code to get post with less than 22 views

```
 <?php query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'views', 'orderby' => 'desc', 'meta_value'  => '22', 'meta_compare' => '<=', 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

While comparing numbers in meta value use "meta_value_num" instead of "meta_value"

> 'meta_value_num' - Order by numeric meta value (available with Version
> 2.8).  Also **note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in the query**.  This value allows for numerical sorting as noted above
> in 'meta_value'.

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)